# Apache Flink InvocationTargetException: Job execution failed. Connection timed out

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am creating [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html) example from the quickstart guide for Apache Flink. I always keep getting the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project wiki-edits: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Job execution failed. Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
```

with a lot of exceptions coming from Flink's internal files and not the file I am coding. Can anyone give a solution to this problem?

Here is the full exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:714)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:660)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:660)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.schwering.irc.lib.IRCConnection.connect(IRCConnection.java:295)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditEventIrcStream.start(WikipediaEditEventIrcStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditsSource.open(WikipediaEditsSource.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:38)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:214)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the exceptions coming from Flink's internal files? This will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Added the full stack trace @rmetzger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `WikipediaEditsSource` can not establish the connection to the IRC channel containing the Wikiedits.

The source is subscribing to an IRC channel where Wikipedia is posting edits. It may be possible that the typical **IRC ports (6667, 6668, ..) are blocked in your network**.

Can you check whether you can reach `irc.wikimedia.org:6667` from your network? The channel is `#en.wikipedia`.

Comment: `irc.wikimedia.org` is not opening in any browser from both my work and mobile networks.

Comment: You need to use an IRC client to connect to the server. I don't think they have a service running on the usual HTTP ports (your browser will try to connect to port 80, not 6667). Even if you instruct your browser to access port 6667, it won't work because its the wrong protocol.

Comment: * Looking up irc.wikimedia.org
* Connecting to argon.wikimedia.org (208.80.154.160) port 6667...
* Connection failed. Error: Connection timed out
 Cycling to next server in WikiEdits...
* Disconnected ().

Comment: So it seems that you can not establish a connection to IRC servers from your network.
Many companies, universities etc. block IRC because some botnets rely on IRC for Command-and-Control.